# Flutter can't switch channel to beta

Tags: git, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-channel

I'm trying to switch the channel of Flutter to use Flutter web. But every time I'm getting this error. Neither its switching to Flutter master nor Flutter beta.

```
P:\FlutterProjects>flutter channel master
Switching to flutter channel 'master'...
git: From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
git:    1ad9baa8b..8af6b2f03  stable         -> origin/stable
git: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/beta': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/beta': reference broken
git:  ! [new branch]          beta           -> origin/beta  (unable to update local ref)
git:    1ad9baa8b..8af6b2f03  flutter-1.17-candidate.3 -> origin/flutter-1.17-candidate.3
git:    df98ad6b2..0bffc8a39  master         -> origin/master
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.5         -> 1.17.5
git: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.20.0-0.0.pre': unable to resolve reference 'refs/tags/1.20.0-0.0.pre': reference broken
git:  ! [new tag]             1.20.0-0.0.pre -> 1.20.0-0.0.pre  (unable to update local ref)
Switching channels failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command line navigate to the directory where flutter is installed and run the following commands

```
$ rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/beta
$ git fetch
```

If the above does not work, try the following

```
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git remote prune origin
```

The commands above will remove the broken reference and the commands below will ensure flutter is fully upgraded on the current channel before changing the channel.

```
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter channel master
$ flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer but I'm sorry to tell you it didn't work, I tried removing beta by myself from the directory but git fetch still showing the same error/

Comment: Hey @Prateek, I just updated the answer with more commands you could try